# AngularJS access Data from Resource Query

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, jersey

I have a Jersey Rest Application which I d'like to access with a AngularJS application.

I have defined the resource as follows:

Service:

```
angular.service('Wine', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/myserver/rest/wines/:wineId', {}, {
        update: {method:'PUT'},
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
function WineListCtrl(Wine) {
    this.wines = Wine.query();
}
```

In Firebug I can see the result of this GET-Request:

```
{"wine":[{"country":"USA","description":"With hints of ginger and spice, this wine makes an excellent complement to light appetizer and dessert fare for a holiday gathering.","grapes":"Pinot Noir","id":"9","name":"BLOCK NINE","picture":"block_nine.jpg","region":"California","year":"2009"},{"country":"Argentina","description":"Solid notes of black currant blended with a light citrus make this wine an easy pour for varied palates.","grapes":"Pinot Gris","id":"11","name":"BODEGA LURTON","picture":"bodega_lurton.jpg","region":"Mendoza","year":"2011"},{"country":"France","description":"The aromas of fruit and spice give one a hint of the light drinkability of this lovely wine, which makes an excellent complement to fish dishes.","grapes":"Grenache / Syrah","id":"1","name":"CHATEAU DE SAINT COSME","picture":"saint_cosme.jpg","region":"Southern Rhone / Gigondas","year":"2009"},{"country":"France","description":"Though dense and chewy, this wine does not overpower with its finely balanced depth and structure. It is a truly luxurious experience for the\nsenses.","grapes":"Merlot","id":"7","name":"CHATEAU LE DOYENNE","picture":"le_doyenne.jpg","region":"Bordeaux","year":"2005"},{"country":"France","description":"The light golden color of this wine belies the bright flavor it holds. A true summer wine, it begs for a picnic lunch in a sun-soaked vineyard.","grapes":"Merlot","id":"8","name":"DOMAINE DU BOUSCAT","picture":"bouscat.jpg","region":"Bordeaux","year":"2009"},{"country":"USA","description":"Though subtle in its complexities, this wine is sure to please a wide range of enthusiasts. Notes of pomegranate will delight as the nutty finish completes the picture of a fine sipping experience.","grapes":"Pinot Noir","id":"10","name":"DOMAINE SERENE","picture":"domaine_serene.jpg","region":"Oregon","year":"2007"},{"country":"Spain","description":"A resurgence of interest in boutique vineyards has opened the door for this excellent foray into the dessert wine market. Light and bouncy, with a hint of black truffle, this wine will not fail to tickle the taste buds.","grapes":"Tempranillo","id":"2","name":"LAN RIOJA CRIANZA","picture":"lan_rioja.jpg","region":"Rioja","year":"2006"},{"country":"France","description":"Breaking the mold of the classics, this offering will surprise and undoubtedly get tongues wagging with the hints of coffee and tobacco in\nperfect alignment with more traditional notes. Breaking the mold of the classics, this offering will surprise and\nundoubtedly get tongues wagging with the hints of coffee and tobacco in\nperfect alignment with more traditional notes. Sure to please the late-night crowd with the slight jolt of adrenaline it brings.","grapes":"Chardonnay","id":"12","name":"LES MORIZOTTES","picture":"morizottes.jpg","region":"Burgundy","year":"2009"},{"country":"USA","description":"The cache of a fine Cabernet in ones wine cellar can now be replaced with a childishly playful wine bubbling over with tempting tastes of\nblack cherry and licorice. This is a taste sure to transport you back in time.","grapes":"Sauvignon Blanc","id":"3","name":"MARGERUM SYBARITE","picture":"margerum.jpg","region":"California Central Cosat","year":"2010"},{"country":"USA","description":"A one-two punch of black pepper and jalapeno will send your senses reeling, as the orange essence snaps you back to reality. Don't miss\nthis award-winning taste sensation.","grapes":"Syrah","id":"4","name":"OWEN ROE \"EX UMBRIS\"","picture":"ex_umbris.jpg","region":"Washington","year":"2009"},{"country":"USA","description":"One cannot doubt that this will be the wine served at the Hollywood award shows, because it has undeniable star power. Be the first to catch\nthe debut that everyone will be talking about tomorrow.","grapes":"Pinot Noir","id":"5","name":"REX HILL","picture":"rex_hill.jpg","region":"Oregon","year":"2009"},{"country":"Italy","description":"Though soft and rounded in texture, the body of this wine is full and rich and oh-so-appealing. This delivery is even more impressive when one takes note of the tender tannins that leave the taste buds wholly satisfied.","grapes":"Sangiovese Merlot","id":"6","name":"VITICCIO CLASSICO RISERVA","picture":"viticcio.jpg","region":"Tuscany","year":"2007"}]}
```

In my html page I d'like to access the content as following:

```
<ul ng:controller="WineListCtrl">
    <li ng:repeat="wine in wines">
        <a href='#/wines/{{ wine.id }}'>{{ wine.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sadly there are no results showing up in the UI (although the JSON Result seems to be okay and there is no error on the Browser Console).

If I make an alert like

```
alert(this.wines.length)
```

I get 0 as result.

Would be great to get some help of you guys...

Greets
Marc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're assigning to `this` and not the scope. If you don't assign to the scope, your data won't be available for binding in the view. So inject the `$scope` into your controller and assign it the `wines` attribute:

```
function WineListCtrl($scope, Wine) {
  $scope.wines = Wine.query();
}
```

You have another problem though. The `ngResource` module expects the result of call to `query` to be an array, but you're actually returning an object:

```
{wine: [an array of wines]}
```

So unless you remove the key from the server-side response, your `ng-repeat` might have to look something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="wine in wines.wine">...</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I get the following exception:

Unknown provider for $scope

Do I have to set this elsewhere too?

Comment: Have you set up an `ng-app` somewhere?

Comment: `<html ng-app="someapp">`, and then in your JS: `var someapp = angular.module('someapp', ['ngResource']);`

Comment: I have done that. Now the Controller doesnt gets called any more... 

function WineListCtrl($scope, Wine) {
 alert('TEST');
    $scope.wines = Wine.query();
}

any ideas? there is no error on web browser console..

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your example (modified) in action. I've faked the resource by just returning the data. You can take a look to see how it fits together. http://jsfiddle.net/uuGMY/

Comment: thank you so much. that works. but as soon as I replace your service with the following, nothing appears. The Rest Call isnt even executed...

WinesApp.service('Wine', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/WinesServer/rest/wines/:wineId', {}, {
        update: {method:'PUT'},
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});


the following error appears on the console:
Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- Wine

Comment: I think I did it. Had to replace isArray:true with false. Now its running. How can I change the return type of my Rest-Service to return an array, so that I can avoid to call wine in wines.wine and use wine in wines?

current Rest-Method:

 @GET
 @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
 public List<Wine> findAll(@Context SecurityContext sc) {
  System.out.println("findAll");
  return dao.findAll();
 }

Thank you so much for your help, satchmorun.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24652/discussion-between-mooon-and-satchmorun)